# Resetting phone to one big internal disk?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, 8.0-oreo, adoptable-storage

My phone has 32GB internal storage and 128GB external (SD-card). Internal has 20GB to use for data and apps, of which 19GB is used. TomTom Go uses 6GB of internal storage. I can't move it to external storage.

I've heard that with Android 8 you can merge internal and external storage, but it needs a complete reset of the phone, removing all apps, data and settings. I'm prepared to do this, but I can't find the proper manual how to do this.

I got this phone with Android 7, then upgraded to 8.0 and I heard that when you start out with 8 it is the default setting. **So is resetting enough?**

**Now what happens when my SD-card crashes?** It has happened before. The SD-card is gone of course, but what will happen to the phone? What happens when I eject the SD-card? **Does Android keep the base system safe, so most important apps on the internal storage?**

Comment: That was in fact introduced with Android 6 and is called adoptable storage. Please take a look at our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](/tags/adoptable-storage/info) to make yourself familiar with this. AFAIK it does NOT require a complete reset.